# Remove repository in plesk doesn't really remove

Tags: git, push, plesk

I was having trouble with pushing to a git i made in Plesk. It was pushing, but files never made it into the httpdocs folder. In Plesk there weren't any Branches showing up so i decided to remove the Git (by using the button in Plesk).

Inside Plesk the git seems removed as it shows up nowhere en i am able to create a new git. But.. The git is still there. Because when i use Sourcetree to fetch the from the old Git-link i still find a "master" branch with stuff in it.

Making a new git is now problematic because Plesk will not give any errors, but the link seem to be referring to the old removed (but not really removed) git.

Is there a way to fully remove the git i made?

For further details.. I just added a git to one of the subdomains and it worked flawless at first try.

Answer (score 0):

pls. check your vhosts - structure at

```
/var/www/vhosts/YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/
```

or/and

```
/var/www/vhosts/YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/SUBDOMAIN.YOUR-DOMAIN.COM
```

... which might not been deleted in case of chrooted environments are used for the subscription.

Pls. delete the found git - folder manually, if you experience described issues.